# How to append images with the correct height, without overlap using masonry and imagesloaded plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry, imagesloaded

Presently on my site I am using imagesloaded to do masonry once all images have loaded for all items. But this is causing a cascade of items (item divs arranged one below the other) until all the images are loaded and then masonry happens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){do_masonry();});

function do_masonry(){
var $container = $('#content');
var gutter = 10;
var min_width = 200;
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
   $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.item',
        gutterWidth: gutter,
        isAnimated: true,
        columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
           //some calculations to set each item div's width
            return item_width;
          }
    });
```

I would like to do masonry immediately on document ready and then append images as they are loaded into each div that forms an item but when I try this, the result looks ugly with divs overlapping vertically in masonry layout.

Am wondering how to accomplish lazy loading the images with correct heights to each divs without overlapping using masonry append?

Comment: You need to post more of your code or make a jsfiddle. Where are you calling do_masonry? where is your append and lazy loading code?

Comment: @Macsupport Am calling do_masonry on document ready. And not using masonry append function as I am not sure how to use it to unhide and insert divs as and when images are completely loaded for each of them.